# what does "fragment operation is modifying it in the activity" mean?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

From official [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle) :

> **onPause()** fragment is no longer interacting with the user either because its activity is being paused or a fragment operation is modifying it in the activity.

First part is clear, activiy being paused causes fragment to pause.

What does *fragment operation is modifying it in the activity* mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Activity` or anything else that has a reference to your [`FragmentManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) can for example remove you. The fragment would then be stopped before it's Activity is stopped.

So I guess *fragment operation* really means [`FragmentTransaction`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)